# stop immediate action with jQuery keyup

Tags: jquery

I want to just allow 0-9 keys and backspace key to be inputted by user in some textbox and want to not allow others. I have tried this but this is not working..

```
 $('#UnitDistance').on('keyup', function (event) {
    var x = event.keyCode;        
    if (x != 8 || x < 48 || x > 57) {  // 48-57 is the code for key 0-9 .. 8 is backspace                      
        $('#UnitDistance').val('');
 });
```

Is there any better ideas doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a look to `<input type='number' />` ,depending on your need,otherwise try this.

```
$('#UnitDistance').on('keyup', function (event) {
    var b=$(this).val();
    b=b.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')
    $(this).val(b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just to adjusted your condition take a look at **[WORKED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8zbke3ob/)**.

**Update part :**

```
 if (x != 8 && (x < 96 || x > 105)) {  // 96-105 is the code for key 0-9
```

**Full JS :**

```
$('#UnitDistance').on('keyup',function(event){
    var x = event.keyCode;   

     if (x != 8 && (x < 96 || x > 105)) {  // 96-105 is the code for key 0-9 .. 8 is backspace     
            $('#UnitDistance').val('');
     }
})
```